# How can I improve 酒吧漆黑的墙面稀疏地装饰着粉红樱花图案 to describe a floral pattern on the black walls of a bar?

Tags: translation, writing-critique

I'm trying to describe the walls in a bar (in my story), and this is what I've come up with:

> 酒吧漆黑的墙面稀疏地装饰着粉红樱花图案。

Essentially, there's a bar and it's walls are painted black, except for a pink cherry-blossom motif which occurs infrequently.

Describing things in detail seems to be a major obstacle for me at the moment.  I'd prefer to keep [漆黑](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%BC%86%E9%BB%91) and [装饰](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%A3%85%E9%A5%B0) in the sentence which are words I should learn, the others are not so important.

**Question**: How can I improve this sentence?

I'm particularly uncomfortable with 装饰着 as it sounds "active".

---

In case it's of any help:

> The bar's painted-black walls are sparsely decorated with a pink cherry-blossom motif.
>   酒吧的粉刷成黑色的墙壁稀疏地装饰着粉红色的樱桃花图案。
>   <sub>[Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=zh-CN&text=The%20bar's%20painted-black%20walls%20are%20sparsely%20decorated%20with%20a%20pink%20cherry-blossom%20motif.)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 酒吧漆黑的墙面稀疏地装饰着粉红樱花图案。

--> 酒吧漆黑的墙面[上]，稀疏地[點綴]着粉红[色的]樱花图案。 --> **粉红色的樱花图案，稀疏地點綴着酒吧漆黑的墙面。**

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion is already pretty good now!

There are other possible ways to express the same thing:

装饰在酒吧漆黑墙面上的，是稀疏的粉红樱花图案。

粉红的樱花图案，稀疏地装饰在酒吧漆黑的墙面上。

Answer (score 0):

酒吧漆黑的墙面上稀稀拉拉地贴着几片粉色樱花图案。

(Don't go to the bar, you might get the 病毒！）